Inequality $\langle 3c_2-c_1^2,[X]\rangle\geq 0$ on Chern Classes
Let $(X,\omega_g)$ be a compact Kähler surface, and its first Chern class is negative. Denote the $i$th Chern class of the holomorphic line bundle $T^{1,0}X$ by $c_i\in H^{2i}(X,\mathbb{R})$. I'm trying to show that
$$\left\langle 3c_2-c_1^2,[X]\right\rangle\geq 0.$$
Now my idea is to use the special Kähler metric to compute its corresponding integral of Chern-form. Could someone provide more details or an explicit answer to help me?

It seems you know what you need to do already. Have you tried it?

@ArcticChar I note that my question seems to relate to Bogomolov–Miyaoka–Yau inequality, right?

Can you provide some background, references, or some computation attempts?
